# Why is this connection string invalid?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I read:
[This ASP.NET page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string)
whatched through the whole EF part of this [pluralsight tutorial](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m4-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building)
And read nearly every web page ( including SO ones ) containing this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

I still do not understand why this connection string is invalid:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"          connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-couleur-emotion.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-couleur-emotion;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My DBContext looks like this:

```
namespace couleur_emotion.Models
{
    public class CouleurEmotionDB : DbContext
    {
        public CouleurEmotionDB()
            : base("name==DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<PageModel> Pages {get;set;}
    }
}
```

I've tried many different connection strings. Not even once was the database file even created. IT fails at the first call to:

```
var model = _db.Pages.ToList();
```

When trying to create the DB. Note the above line is in a class containing:

```
CouleurEmotionDB _db = new CouleurEmotionDB();
```

Comment: maybe because: `Integrated Security=true`

Comment: Can you explain ? I have the same problem without it though...

Comment: I think you need to pass `"DefaultConnection"` to the base constructor in your context class instead of `"name==DefaultConnection"`. I assume the name lookup is failing and it is being interpreted as an (invalid) connection string.

Comment: In your class, shouldn't it be `base("name=DefaultConnection")` (with a single equal sign rather than two)?

Comment: Thanks you so much, I am just so sorry for that one... And a bit shameful...

Comment: So who's comment answered your question? How about posting it as an answer?

Comment: @t3chb0t both upvoted comments gave the same answer in a few seconds interval.